# Cygwin bash files

Tags: linux, cygwin

About a year ago, I created a couple text files called "compile" and "pull." When I go into a cygwin prompt and type those names and hit enter (basically use them as a command), the cygwin terminal runs what is in those text files. For instance here is the contents of one:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -- .
```

I don't even remember how  I did this. I'm pretty sure this is not a bash script.

I do remember that I had to not just create the file in notepad but also perform some linux command line operation on it, in order to use it. Once I did that I could basically use the file as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *nix, you have to make a file executable in order to be able to run it:

```
chmod u+x file
```

You also need to add the path to the file to the PATH variable

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/file
```

or, add `.` to always scan the current directory for commands (it's considered unsecure, though):

```
PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: Ah, that was it. Now that I have the name of the command I can go from there.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I know it was chmod that I used before though so that definitely helps.

Comment: For future reference, you have to change the path via Windows. The cygwin PATH comes from Windows and doesn't save permanently using PATH=$PATH/... It does save, but only while that terminal is open.

Comment: @Lokor: You need to save the command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` to take effect, same as on *nix.